# How to compare arrays and create a final array using js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, compare

I have two array of objects they are:

Object 1:

```
    [  
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   }
]
```

Object 2:
[
   {
      "sku":"30772",
      "qty":"1"
   },
   {
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   }
]

Object 2:

```
[  
   {  
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   }
]
```

I need to compare the the object parameters namely position and tech and need to get the final array in which that position and object available like below

Final output:

```
[  

   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   }
]
```

Comment: The first object and the final object are exactly the same except the key positionName is changed to position. Is that something you want? Replacing positionName by position if position and positionName matches in both the objects?

Comment: sorry I have edited my question..just a careless mistake.

Comment: So now, the final output must only contain position matching in object 1 and object 2, right?

Comment: yes the matching object of object 2 in object 1 should return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The code is pretty self-explanatory.

**EDIT:** **The code now is more efficient, we determine the length of both the arrays and run the loop with less number of objects.**

```js
var obj1 =   [  
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   }
]

var obj2 = [  
   {  
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   }
]

const doer = (ob1, ob2) => {
  
  let final = [];
  ob1.map((one) => {
    // let tobepushed = one.hasOwnPropery('id') ? one : two;
    ob2.map(two => {
      if(two.hasOwnProperty('position') && 
          two.hasOwnProperty('tech') && 
          two['position'] === one['position'] && 
          two['tech'] === one['tech']
        ) {
        final.push('id' in one ? one : two);
      }
    })
  })

  return final;
}

let l1 = obj1.length;
let l2 = obj2.length

if(l1 < l2) {
  console.log(doer(obj2, obj1))
} else if (l2 < l1) {
  console.log(doer(obj1, obj2))
}

// console.log(doer(obj2, obj1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use lodash then you can use `intersectionWith` method as it is intuitive that you want interesection based on two keys.

```js
const object1 = [
  {
    id: "30772",
    posimage: "/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
    position: "Position Chest",
    tech: "Embroidery"
  },
  {
    id: "30772",
    posimage: "/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
    position: "Position Chest",
    tech: "Screenprint Textile"
  },
  {
    id: "30772",
    posimage: "/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
    position: "Position Arm Left",
    tech: "Embroidery"
  },
  {
    id: "30772",
    posimage: "/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
    position: "Position Arm Left",
    tech: "Screenprint Textile"
  }
];

const object2 = [
  {
    position: "Position Arm Left",
    tech: "Embroidery"
  },
  {
    position: "Position Chest",
    tech: "Screenprint Textile"
  }
];

const result = _.intersectionWith(
  object1,
  object2,
  (o1, o2) => o1.position === o2.position && o1.tech === o2.tech
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think this will help you to get your desire answer.

```
const object1 = [  
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "id":"30772",
      "posimage":"/b/l/blue-shirt_1_1.jpg",
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   }
];

const object2 = [  
   {  
      "position":"Position Arm Left",
      "tech":"Embroidery"
   },
   {  
      "position":"Position Chest",
      "tech":"Screenprint Textile"
   }
];

const findObject = object1.filter(obj1 => {
  const mathObject = object2.find(obj2 => {
    return obj2.tech === obj1.tech && obj2.position === obj1.position;
  });
  return mathObject;
});

console.log(findObject);
```